# Passing variables into class variable methods

Tags: c++

Currently using C++20.

Given the layout shown below, what would be the most optimal way of passing the `registry` variable to the `renderEngine` variable's class methods that need it?

The registry class is an entity-component system (3rd Party Library) used to hold data for an arbitrary number of 'entities'.

I'm trying to avoid creating a chain of passing arguments down one function after another, just so I can pass the registry to the method that uses it.

Should I make the `Renderer` class hold a reference or pointer to the `registry` variable?

Or should I make the class methods that need the `registry` variable take an extra argument?

```
class Renderer
{
private:
    void func1()
    {
        func2();
    }

    void func2()
    {
        func3();
    }

    void func3() // Needs registry
    {
        // Do stuff with registry
    }

public:
    render()
    {
        func1();
    }
}


class GameEngine
{
    Renderer renderEngine;
    entt::registry registry;
}
```

Comment: Depends on how you want to use it and how heavy it is to move/copy. I’d go for passing by const reference based on what little context we have.

Comment: What if the class methods that need the `registry` variable are only callable inside the `Renderer` class, such that it may require a long chain of passing arguments?

Comment: What's the problem if pass by reference like `Renderer::render(entt::entity& registry)`? If not, why?

Comment: Ask yourself to what degree it should be part of the renderer. If it should be, should it be owned by the renderer or should the renderer just have access? I think passing the argument around is probably best even if it’s more code.

Comment: @LouisGo I've updated the layout above to give clearer context.

Comment: You haven’t clarified the question. The problem isn’t that you have a code problem; you have a _design_ problem. What is the registry class? How does it relate to your renderer? Does your renderer use multiple registry classes at any given time? How is it attached to the things you are rendering? You need to design an object system that works together, and all we can do is guess at that system’s current structure.

Comment: @Ben Both the `GameEngine` and the `Renderer` access and modify the `registry`, so it's basically shared data. I just declared it in the `GameEngine` class because that class holds a `Renderer` class variable. I always struggle with creating levels and abstractions whilst trying to retain encapsulation.

Comment: Must they use the same registry class instance?

Comment: There is little context. The design problem should includes what you want to avoid and how big the `registry` is. So far `GameEngine` and the `Renderer` shares `registry`. I'd say just use dependency injection to `Renderer` should be suffice. And take care of data race if you share data between two objects.

Comment: @Dúthomhas I've briefly described the registry class in the new edit. I'm only saying they must use the same registry class instance because I'm not sure how else I can use it.

Comment: Also sharing them might not be a good way to work. Just like @Dúthomhas asked. What if `Renderer` draws something in the middle of creation/copy?